# Помогите пожалуйста c последним тестом в задании PhoneBook! TreeSet

Tags: java, test-automation, set, treemap, treeset

**Цель задания**

Научиться работать с коллекцией Map.

**Что нужно сделать**

Задание выполняйте в проекте

09_ArraysAndCollections/homework_9.4/PhoneBook

1. Напишите программу, которая будет работать как телефонная книга:

Если вводим новое имя, программа просит ввести номер телефона и запоминает его.
Если новый номер телефона — просит ввести имя и также запоминает.
Если вводим существующее имя или номер телефона, программа выводит телефон(ы) или имя абонента соответственно.
При вводе команды LIST программа печатает в консоль список всех абонентов в алфавитном порядке с номерами.
2. Определяйте имя и телефон с помощью регулярных выражений.

3. Подумайте, что выбрать в качестве ключа и значения для Map, и выберите лучший, по вашему мнению, вариант. Опишите, какие минусы и плюсы видите в своём выборе.
4. Для работы с данными телефонной книги в проекте находится класс PhoneBook, который должен отвечать за хранение и работу с абонентами. Реализуйте все методы и проверьте класс с помощью существующих тестов. Вы можете добавлять дополнительные методы в класс.

Команды вводятся пользователем в консоль одной строкой.
Помогите пожалуйста c последним тестом в задании!

У меня проходят все тесты кроме одного:

```
@DisplayName("Добавление контакта, владеющий двумя номерами")
    void addContactWithTwoNumbers() {
        phoneBook.addContact("79001234567", "Маша");
        phoneBook.addContact("79007654321", "Маша");
        Set<String> expected = new TreeSet<>(List.of("Маша - 79001234567, 79007654321"));
        assertEquals(expected, phoneBook.getAllContacts());
```

Мне посоветовали, что нужно пройтись в цикле по мапе где хранятся телефон и имя Map<String, String> он же Map <phone, name> и переложить в новую мапу Map<String, Treeset>, в виде ключа положить имя, в виде значения телефон в treeset и если встретится такое же имя, докладывать телефон в Treeset, а после цикла for уже объединять ключ и значение (имя контакта с номерами телефонов) в Set.

Но я не понимаю, как это реализовать, буду очень признателен, если кто-нибудь сможет помочь подправить код!

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class PhoneBook {

    Map<String, String> mapPhoneBook = new TreeMap<>();

    public void addContact(String phone, String name) {

        if (phone.matches("[\\d]{11}") && name.matches("[А-Яа-я]+")) {
            if (mapPhoneBook.containsKey(phone)) {
                mapPhoneBook.replace(phone, mapPhoneBook.get(phone), name);
            } else {
                mapPhoneBook.put(phone, name);
            }
        }
    }


    public String getContactByPhone(String phone) {
        if (mapPhoneBook.containsKey(phone)) {
            return mapPhoneBook.get(phone) + " - " + phone;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }


    public Set<String> getContactByName(String name) {

        Set<String> setPhoneBook = new TreeSet<>();
        String namePlusTel = "";
        if (mapPhoneBook.containsValue(name)) {
            namePlusTel = namePlusTel.concat(name) + " - ";
            for (String tel : mapPhoneBook.keySet()) {
                if (mapPhoneBook.get(tel).equals(name)) {
                    namePlusTel = namePlusTel.concat(tel) + ", ";
                }
            }
            setPhoneBook.add(namePlusTel.substring(0, namePlusTel.length() - 2));
            return setPhoneBook;
        } else {
            return new TreeSet<>();
        }
    }

    public Set<String> getAllContacts() {

        Set<String> setPhoneBook = new TreeSet<>();

        for (String key : mapPhoneBook.keySet()) {
            setPhoneBook.add(mapPhoneBook.get(key) + " - " + key);
        }
        return setPhoneBook;
    }
}
```

Comment: Лучше добавьте в вопрос задание, входные данные и ожидаемый результат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это далеко не самый лучший код, который можно было написать, однако он решает вашу задачу, а вот поработать над его улучшением оставляю вам

```
    public Set<String> getSetFromMap(Map<String, String> phoneToName) {
    Map<String, TreeSet<String>> nameToPhones = new HashMap<>();
    for (String key : phoneToName.keySet()) {
        String name = phoneToName.get(key);
        if (!nameToPhones.containsKey(name)) {
            nameToPhones.put(name, new TreeSet<>());
        }
        nameToPhones.get(name).add(key);
    }

    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
    for (String key : nameToPhones.keySet()) {
        String resultString = key + " - " + nameToPhones.get(key);
        result.add(resultString.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]",""));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Мой рабочий вариант метода который принимает Имя и Новый телефон (второй для нашего контакта) и возвращает TreeSet, а главное добавляет новый контакт с двумя телефонами удаляя старый контакт с одним номером.
Данный метод не только вернет TreeSet в нужном формате контакта с двумя номерами, но и добавит этот контакт в Map, удалив контакт с таким же именем но одним номером

```
public Set<String> getContactTwoNumbers(String phone, String name) {
    TreeSet<String> result = new TreeSet<>();
    String key = "";
    String namePlusNumber = "";
    if (phoneBookTreeMap.containsValue(name)){
        for(String k : phoneBookTreeMap.keySet())
        {
            if (phoneBookTreeMap.get(k).equals(name)){
                key = k;
                result.add(name + " - " + key + ", " + phone); 
                namePlusNumber = key + ", " + phone;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    phoneBookTreeMap.remove(key); // сюда передаем старый контакт по номеру (key) и удаляем его, чтобы остался в Map только один контакт с двумя номерами
    phoneBookTreeMap.put(namePlusNumber, name); // сюда добавляем в наш Map "новый" контакт уже с двумя номерами
    return result;
}
```